# How to individually define line properties in plotyy() for multiple datasets plotted in right Y-axis

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Consider the following example from MATLAB help.

[image]

```
x = linspace(0,10);
y1 = 200*exp(-0.05*x).*sin(x);
y2 = 0.8*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);
y3 = 0.2*exp(-0.5*x).*sin(10*x);

figure
[hAx,hLine1,hLine2] = plotyy(x,y1,[x',x'],[y2',y3']);
```

I need to individually define the colors for the two plots in the right Y axis. Also, How can we define the text color in the right and left YLabels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Examine `hLine2`, the handle for the second axis. It's actually a 2x1 vector in this example, corresponding to the handle for the first and second lines, respectively.

```
set(hLine2(1), 'Color', desired_color_1)
set(hline2(2), 'Color', desired_color_2)
```

Similarly, the axis handle, `hAx`, is a 2x1 vector, which gives you access to the axis properties of the left and right axes, respectively. For instance:

```
set(hAx(1), 'LineWidth', 2)
```

To access deeper child properties such as text labels:

```
h_ylab_1 = get(hAx(1), 'YLabel');
set(h_ylab_1, 'String', 'YLabel text')
set(h_ylab_1, 'Color', desired_text_color)
```